# "not as strong" vs. "less strong" --- interchangeable?

Tags: phrase-meaning, comparative-constructions, quantifiers

> David is much
>   smaller than Andrew
>   and (is) less strong.
>
> David is much
>   smaller than Andrew
>   and (is) not as strong.

Answer (score 2):

In this usage, you can use them interchangeably.

Strictly, the first meaning is <, and the second meaning is ≠.